# Flutter - How can I access current selected item in DropDown from other widget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a *DropDown* in my code. I need to somehow access my currently selected item from other widget.
How can I access this item in other widget? Can I do it with GlobalKey or constructor or anything else?

Code of my DropDown:

```
              DropdownButton<String>(
                    items: _myList.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: dropDownStringItem,
                        child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (String newItemSelected) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentItemSelected = newItemSelected;
                      });
                    },
                    value: currentItemSelected,
                  ),
```

Comment: You just need to pass the currentItemSelected value to the widget you want. You can simply use a constructor or pass route arguments (If you are using named routes). A global key will work too but it might be an overkill for a single piece of information that you might want to transfer. However, If you are willing to make changes to the value in the other widget, you should probably go with a global key.

Comment: How can I use the constructor with my dropDown? If i do it like this: `onChanged: (String newItemSelected) {SecondWidget(currentItemSelected);}` and set the constructor in SecondWidget or course... I get *null value*. How can i correctly setup this constructor?

Comment: Can you post the code of the class containing this dropdown and explain a bit about what you want to happen when the new item is selected? It will be easier to explain that way.

Comment: [Here is my full code](https://pastebin.com/nFx79S1X) If I select an item in DropDown it should pass that item to my Button widget. When I press the button it should set text of textfield to the selected item. Or print that item... I just need to somehow pass that to other class...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are creating a button in the function but not mounting it in the widget tree. See in my example code, I used a column to place the dropdown and a button. Whenever I make changes to the dropdown, the currentItemSelected changes and so does the button text. In button's onPressed, you can use the navigator to navigate to another page by passing currentItemSelected value to its constructor. This way, you can send information to the next page.

Here is a small example. [Dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/ef8f26289760aa21b5732c881ce42810)